# Class Diagram: In A Composition Relationship Should a Child Class Always Have An ID Field?

Tags: oop, database-design, uml, relation, class-diagram

I'm having a hard time converting my database tables and foreign keys to a class diagram with classes and associations.

My question is:
**"In in a composition relationship, should a child class always should have an ID field?"**.

In my CD, there are 2 compositor classes: ***PurchaseItem*** and ***PurchaseFinisher***, which composite ***Purchase*** class. ***PurchaseItem*** already comes with an ID field from its table but, ***PurchaseFinisher*** doesn't because it is filtered by the *id_purchase* and *id_payment_method* foreign keys.

thanks in advance.

[image]

This is my **DB diagram**:

[image]

I can't see redundancy in between `Purchase` or `Product`, as you said. Could you, please, show me that based on my DB diagram? My tables are well modeled (hope so). My fault is in the classes definition.

Comment: you haven't shape your question

Comment: @woodz sorry but, I don't know why it is not well shaped. could you help me, please?

Comment: what is your effective question to which concrete problem? Is there something not working as you expect?

Comment: my effective question is **if, in a composition relationship, a child class always should have an ID field**. the class diagram is to show how my project effectively is now and to show both cases of child class happening: one with ID field and one without ID field.

Comment: are you asking because of well established formality or because of further technical diagram processing and auto code generation? It's also not clear how you work in VBA with a class diagram, since you didn't mention it in a tag

Comment: @woodz I didn't mention VBA in a tag due to the fact that the question has to do with class diagram, relational mapping, oop... not about VBA programming. what I've done so far is to model the system tables. the next step is to define the classes, which I'm facing problem because I need to do a well-done relational mapping. my question has everything to do with I'm experiencing now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236935/discussion-between-woodz-and-alex-boorjs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a class diagram, no class requires an id property: each class instance (aka object) has its own identity with or without explicit id property.

In a database, you need of course an explicit id property to uniquely identify the object among others in the database and find it back. By the way, you may annotate such properties with a trailing `{id}` . UML does not define any semantic for it, but it is in general sufficiently expressive to help database designers.

In the case of composition, the main question is whether a composed object can easily be identified by alternate means. There are several related ORM database techniques, for example:

- you can use the owning object’s id together with another property if this is sufficient to identify the element. The two together would make a composite primary key in database.
- you can use a unique id to identify the object (surrogate primary key) and use the id of the owning object as foreign key.

For `PurchaseItem` you have everything that is needed, although the diagram does not tell which of the two approaches you’ll use (e.g is the id unique globally, or unique within the purchase?).

But for `PurchaseFinisher` it is unclear if you could uniquely identify an occurence. If a payment method can only be used once per purchase, it’s fine as it may be used to identify the object.
If it would be allowed to pay two times the same amount (half of the overall price) in the same currency with the same payment methods, you’d have undistinguishable duplicates. So, some kind of identifier will be needed from the database point of view.

Comment: `ID_PurchaseItem` will be reset for every new `Purchase`, so, it will be unique within the Purchase. For `PurchaseFinisher`, it is allowed to pay as much times as needed till cover the total purchase value (`total_purchase`). Well, from the **database point of view** it is solved, once that I let `PurchaseFinisher` unique by **combining** the `Purchase` and `PaymentMethod` **foreign keys**. Right? what about the **class point of view**: should I create an `ID_PurchaseFinisher` in this case?

Comment: @AlexBoorjs If it is as much time as needed, for example for a purchase of 100 a first payment of 40 with credit card  A, 40 with credit card B and 10 with cash, you’n not able to distinguish the two first.  I’d therefore suggest to add an id like for the other table. From a class point of view, it there is an id, it’s a good practice to show it as property.

Comment: man, you're much right! it went unnoticed before all this confusion with classes. normally, it is much common to pay partially in credit card, partially in cash but never (or very seldom) to pay in more than one credit card. I'll do the changes right now. what about in case that it wouldn't be possible to repeat `PurchaseFinisher`? would I still have to create an **ID** for `PurchaseFinisher`?

Comment: @AlexBoorjs If you’d have any property that is not allowed to repeat, you would be in the case where you could just use that propety + the purchase id to uniquely find any finisher. In my own experience however I have been often confronted with cases where such a unicity was assumed and either voided in some special cases (e.g two credit card examples), or because business rules and practices were changed. When there’s an id, at least I know that I don’t need to care for this specific risk

Comment: about those objects and lists inside the classes, derived from **one-to-many** relationships, how do you normally deal with them at the time of **setters** and **validation methods**? for instance: for me to save `PurchaseItem` inside `Purchase`, how and when do I chech that `PurchaseItem` is **valid**? what about if I save `PurchaseItem`, which is fulfilled but with an **invalid** `Product` (some empty attribute)?

Comment: @AlexBoorjs the Purchase or the Product that you showed within the class are in fact redundant with the association/composition/aggregation and are usually. In the database you’d replace them with the id of the associated class. For the validation and the transactional consistency, it’s a much more complex story, far beyond diagramming, and there are even books that address these points. I’d suggest that you look on sofwareengineering.stackexchange.com for similar questions. Of you do not find a relevant one, you can ask there, but you’d need to be much more specific.

Comment: sorry, I can't see that redundancy you pointed. I added my DB diagram so, if you want, to explain me in a better way. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @AlexBoorjs the db diagram is fine. In the class diagram, the notation in a class C of a property X:T where T is another class, is equivalent to an association between C and T having the role “X” (the X would be written on the line on the T end of the line). Having both at same time creates an ambiguity. If the diagram’s purpose is the design, there is no need to add the Purchase in PurchaseItem, since it is implicit from the association (and code generation tools would add the expected purchase_id). If the purpose is to document accurately the implementation, you may explicit the purchase_id

Comment: @AlexBoorjs You may have a look at this article: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html - it proposes a set of «stereotypes» to use UML class diagram for database implementation modeling. The idea is, in the case of purchase_id in purchase, to show that it’s a foreign key that implements an association.

Comment: Christophe if I understood well, the only wrong thing with my class diagram is that `PurchaseItem` should **not** have `Purchase` in it due to the fact that `PurchaseItem` will be saved into Purchase's **arraylist**, which is already inside `Purchase` (that's how ambiguity will happen). so, what I should do **IMMEDIATELY**, before the coffee break, is to remove `Purchase` from both `PurchaseItem` and `PurchaseFinisher`. right? I'm very glad for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237115/discussion-between-alex-boorjs-and-christophe).

Comment: @AlexBoorjs yes, exactly. The association is sufficient. The additional properties for reflecting the detailed implementation should better be avoided, since the implementation will not be the same in the OO language (vba, java, using references and collection of references) and in the rdbms (where foreign keys are used, except for many-to-many that require an additional association table.

Comment: since the beginning that it made more sense to me not to have a reference of `Purchase` inside `PurchaseItem` (or PurchaseFinisher) but in all tutorial videos that I watched from Java programmers, they always place one object inside the composed object (PurchaseItem) representing the **one** side of the **one-to-many** relationship and an **ArrayList** inside the composite object (Purchase) representing the **many** side of the relationship.

Comment: well, as I'm using **VBA**, there's no code generation tool, so, when you told me to remove `Purchase` from `PurchaseItem` is it just for the purpose of diagramming or it also should happen in the programming? maybe Java need this reference on both sides of the related objects, I don't know how Java works in this regard.

Comment: @AlexBoorjs no, the removal is only for diagramming. In the programming you need it to implement the association.

Comment: about programming, should I really have a `Purchase` object inside each `PurchaseItem` object if `Purchase` object has an **ArrayList** of `PurchaseItem` objects in it? on the time that I want to persist **Purchase** along with all **PurchaseItems**, I should just save Purchase data first (on `tblPurchase` table), then, I do a loop in **ArrayList** and save each PurchaseItem (on `tblPurchaseItem` table) associating **Purchase ID** for each item. remember that I'm using VBA, not Java.

Comment: @AlexBoorjs To be precise,  it depends on the navigation:  if you have an array list in purchase and can find the items, this may be sufficient.  But if at some moment in your app you could have an item and must find teh related purchase, you need this link to do it efficiently.

Comment: cool. in this case, I'd better not have a link of `Purchase` inside `PurchaseItem`. what I need to do is to insert **PurchaseItem** into the **ArrayList** and do searches in the list for exclusion, when needed. I'll do the Save method inside **Purchase**, which will persist Purchase data first and then persist all the PurchaseItems in one loop. thanks for recommending me [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).